# create leaf dictionary form parent dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

There is a dictionary say d , let  n > 0

```
d = {
'leaf1': 1,
'leaf2': 2,
'leaf3': 3,
'leaf4': 4,
'leaf5': 5,
'leaf6': 6
}
```

I want to create a list of dictionary (say b) taking n items from d

then when n = 1,

```
b = [{'leaf1': 1},
 {'leaf2': 2},
{'leaf3': 3},
{'leaf4': 4},
{'leaf5': 5},
{'leaf6': 6}]
```

when n = 2, b is

```
b = [{'leaf1': 1, 'leaf2': 2 },
 {'leaf2': 2, 'leaf3': 3},
{'leaf3': 3,'leaf4': 4},
{'leaf4': 4,'leaf5': 5},
{'leaf5': 5,'leaf6': 6},
{'leaf6': 6,'leaf1': 1}]
```

when n = 3, b will be

```
b = {'leaf1': 1, 'leaf2': 2 , 'leaf3': 3},
 {'leaf2': 2, 'leaf3': 3,'leaf4': 4},
{'leaf3': 3,'leaf4': 4,'leaf5': 5},
{'leaf4': 4,'leaf5': 5,'leaf6': 6},
{'leaf5': 5,'leaf6': 6,'leaf1': 1},
{'leaf6': 6,'leaf1': 1,'leaf2': 2}]
```

Comment: Please include your attempts.

Answer (score 1):

To create a list of dictionary with n elements at a time, we can first loop in len(d.keys()) i.e total no of elements in dictionary, then loop through the indices that we have to add in list element. As the index may become greater than length of d.keys(), so I have added a check in the loop, we can reduce index from len(d.keys()) to start from 0.

```
def createLeafDictionary(d, n):
    array = []
    for i in range(len(d.keys())):
        leaf = {}
        keyList = list(d.keys())
        for j in range(i, i+n):
            if j >= len(d.keys()):
                j = j - len(d.keys())
            leaf[keyList[j]] = d[keyList[j]]
        array.append(leaf)
    return array
```

> keyList variable I have used to create a list of dictionary keys, we can access dictionary values with help of it.

Comment: Here I have created a function and rest things look simpler to understand, let me know if you have some doubts.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I have edited my answer and added details.